# Navigate an array from controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good I'm starting with php and codeigniter, I have the following problem I'm running an array from my model, which is the result of a query, how can I read one by one my records in the controller?

```
function getCustomers() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

      $i = 0;

      foreach($query->result() as $row) {
         $img[$i]['id'] = $row->id;
         $img[$i]['name'] = $row->name;
         $img[$i]['Location'] = $row->Location;
         $img[$i]['telephone'] = $row->telephone;

         $i++;
      }
      return $img;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should likely start by reading the tutorial... https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can return array to the controller by loading the model into the controller like this.

```
$this->load->model('yourmodel');

$array = $this->yourmodel->yourmodelsmethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to return this array to your controller like

```
$this->load->model('yourmodel');
$array['test'] = $this->yourmodel->yourmodelsmethod();
foreach($test as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

By doing this you can easily print your data from model in controller